# nested for loops but each loop is in different methods?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a java program with multiple classes, and I have two arraylists of objects in different classes studList which include student objects, and courseList which include course objects and I am trying to prompt the user to enter the CIN of the student, and the course ID and number of units of the course the student wants to add to the courseSchedule which is an arraylist that belongs to Student class. I've been told that the way to do this is by nested for loop where the outer loop and the inner loop are in different methods, and I tried to do this but it didn't work and here is my code, thank you in advance.

```
public void addCourseForStudents() {
    Long CIN;
    System.out.println("please enter your CIN : ");
    CIN = in.nextLong();
    for (Student s : studList) {
        if (s.getStudentCIN().equals(CIN)) {
            outerloop(s);
                }
            }
}
public void outerloop(Student s) {
String courseId;
int numberOfUnits;
int position = 0;
System.out.println(" Enter the course details : ");
System.out.println();
System.out.println(" Enter the course Id : ");
courseId = in.next();
System.out.println(" Enter the number of units : ");
numberOfUnits = in.nextInt();
for (Course c : courseList) {
    if (c.getCourseId().equals(courseId) && numberOfUnits == 
c.getNumberOfUnits()) {
        s.getCourseSchedule().add(c);
    }
    else position++;}
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What is going wrong?

Comment: Oh I've just discovered that it works, but it doesn't show me the reference it is showing me something weird like this lab3.Course@7e0ea639

Comment: Try using  tostring()